# How to Copy Values from one Google Sheet to Another Google Sheet after submitting button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Hy, I am using Google Sheet which is used to calculate the commission of agents. I am not familiar with the Google Script. Here is the link of the Sheet

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10xWoLjsSG6i3ufJX5TLspxMD8bcCvOx9tOr_u7C4ux0/edit?usp=sharing)

I need a script that enables me to copy data from `Calculator` range `B3:B5`, `D3:D5`, and `F3:F5` on the `RawData` sheet.

The script should enable me to copy data every time when I will press the "Submit" button and every time the record should be on the next empty row. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Did this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64133257/11225291) worked for you? this one created the Submit button in your file.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation:

The following script will copy the data from the **Calculator** sheet; ranges `B3:B5`, `D3:D5` and `F3:F5` to the next available row of the **RawData** sheet when you click a button called `Submit`. In your case, I created the button under the `Scripts` menu as you can see in the screenshot below. I already implemented the solution for you in the shared document, therefore you just have to try it out.

---

### Solution:

```
function copyToRawData() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const cal_sh = ss.getSheetByName('Calculator');
  const raw_sh = ss.getSheetByName('RawData');
  const ranges = ['B3:B5','D3:D5','F3:F5'];
  const values = [];
  ranges.forEach(r=>values.push(...cal_sh.getRange(r).getValues().flat()));
  raw_sh.getRange(raw_sh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,values.length).setValues([values]);
  
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Menu')
  .addItem('Submit', 'copyToRawData')
  .addToUi();
}
```

---

### Result:

Here is the submit button that you need to press in order to perform this operation.

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

- Use [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations) to retrieve the [RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list) corresponding to `B3:B5`, `D3:D5`, `F3:F5`.
- Use [getRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#getRanges()), [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()), [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to transform the `RangeList` to a simple array of values corresponding to the source ranges.
- Use [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) to append these values to the first empty row of your destination sheet.
- Attach this function to your desired button (ref: [Clickable images and drawings in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets)).

#### Code sample:

```
function copyData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calculator");
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("RawData");
  const rangeList = sourceSheet.getRangeList(['B3:B5', 'D3:D5', 'F3:F5']);
  const values = rangeList.getRanges().map(range => range.getValues()).flat(2);
  targetSheet.appendRow(values);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a script for that. Please use the following formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(flatten({ Calculator!B3:B5;Calculator!D3:D5;Calculator!F3:F5}))
```

[image]

Please remember that the data will **always** be updated.

Functions used:

- [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- `flatten` Undocumented

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. But is it work with the button? I need a button to press and every time, the data should be copied to another sheet on the next empty row.

Comment: This is working perfectly, but copying the same data on each row. how I can use it for every time for the new record?

Comment: *"...data should be copied to another sheet on the next empty row"*. I see. Sorry I misread the question. You will definitely need a script for that.

Comment: You could use the given formula in a script to do that. Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47916817/1527780) and similar questions.

Comment: @shakeelahmad you mean the submit button ?